# JPG Concatenation with Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, jpeg, concatenation

This is a LONG shot, but maybe someone out here is a super-genius.

I want to combine 4 jpgs in a grid

```
1 2
3 4
```

I want to do this client side, without SVG (because IE blows).

I'm looking at manipulating the code inside the jpg files to produce a single, new image. I will get them as all same-sized jpgs, and I can output them to another format (like bitmap) if necessary. I'm also wiling to accept solutions using any special IE "features" like VML. IE8 is the target audience.

I realize I can do this with SVG. I realize I can do this server-side. I realize I can css them next to each other. I need a single image from the 4 originals, as a string is fine (even preferable) because I can base64 encode it and throw it in an image element.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the problem with doing this server-side? PHP has the [Imagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) library, using that it would be 10 line worst-case, and would save you a lots of time.

Comment: What are the source jpegs? Do you generate or regenerate them? If some options of jpeg are the same I think it can be possible to concatenate them to bigger jpeg without full decompress/compress cycle at client.

Comment: @bali182 Lines of code are not a problem, hundreds of thousands of users generating images on the servers are.

Comment: @osgx The jpegs come from an existing image processor (from user uploads). So they're consistent, but I cannot make changes to them before I get them. I've had a little success copy-pasting jpeg code in a txt editor to manipulate the images, but not to the extent or understanding to change the image size (ie: 4x larger for the 4 images).

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that your only option (on the client) is actually flash based canvas libraries like [FX Canvas](https://code.google.com/p/fxcanvas/) . They give you full complement of standard canvas methods (such as toDataURL which you need the most)... Normally I would not advocate using Flash but using a library emulating canvas will make it a breeze to migrate your code when your client decides to upgrade their browser set.

Comment: It looks that way. The client is going to use canvas/svg for every other browser, but nearly half of their traffic is good ol' IE.